# how to change DataGridCheckBoxColumn value when DataGridTextColumn value changing?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

i'm using wpf with mvvm and i have a datagrid with 4 columns:
ID,Original,Translated,IsTranslated
i want when text in Translated column is changing,value of IsTranslated column automatically change to checked
this is my datagrid xaml code:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AllXliffs}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Original" Binding="{Binding Path=Original}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Translated" Binding="{Binding Path=Translated}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsTranslated"  Binding="{Binding Path=IsTranslated, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToBooleanConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You are using MVVM so you can add a small business logic in your model property :

Like this :

```
        private string _translation;
        private bool _isTranslated;

        public string Translation
        {
            get { return _translation; }
            set
            {
                _translation = value;
                IsTranslated = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_translation);
            }
        }

        public bool IsTranslated
        {
            get { return _isTranslated; }
            set
            {
                _isTranslated = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsTranslated");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind IsTranslated column to Translated binding path, not IsTranslated binding path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <loca:StringToBooleanConverter x:Key="myCon" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Original" Binding="{Binding Path=Original}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Translated" Binding="{Binding Path=Translated}" />
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsTranslated"  Binding="{Binding Path=Translated, Converter={StaticResource myCon}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Converter should look like this:

```
public class StringToBooleanConverter: IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string translated = (string)value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(translated))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {            
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
}
```

Comment: How can he get IsTranslated data incase he wants to get it stored to database?

Comment: He doesn't specify that this value is from DB, he only want automatically change this value to true when text is changed.

Comment: my data come from an xml file and store in it.